# Java character comparison error

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, char, character

```
char studentClass=(char)(br.read());        
if((studentClass>='1' && sudentClass<='10'))
```

I want the program to proceed only if the value entered by the user is between 1 to 10, both inclusive.
When I tried the above code, I am getting an error saying 'unclosed character literal' when I have enclosed both 1 and 10 in single quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`10` is not a single character.
You might want this

```
int studentClass=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());        
if((studentClass>=1 && sudentClass<=10))
```

Answer (score 0):

`'10'` is not a character. It is a set of characters. I wonder why you don't use integers:

```
int studentClass = Integer.valueOf(br.readLine());        
if(studentClass >= 1 && studentClass <= 10) 
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I avoid using int values for choices from the user because if the user enters something like 'a' it gives an error. It has happened to me. Anyways, I appreciate your answer.